# Is $e^{\sqrt{z}}$ an entire function?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I was wondering whether $e^{\sqrt{z}}$ is an entire function. We know that the composition of two entire functions is entire. But $\sqrt{z}$ is a multivalued function which is analytic in the principal branch. So if we take the principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$, is $e^{\sqrt{z}}$ analytic? If so, what is the order of growth of it. The order of growth of an entire function $f$ is defined as
$\sigma=\displaystyle{\limsup\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\log\log M(r,f)}{\log r}}$, where $M(r,f)=\displaystyle{\sup_{|z|=r}|f(z)|}$.

Comment: $e^{\sqrt z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ if we take the principal branch of the square root where the square root of a non-negative real number is also non-negative.

Comment: That means it is not entire. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to ask about the order of growth of $\cosh \sqrt{z}$ instead...

Comment: Is $\cosh\sqrt{z}$ entire? How do we show this? Then what is the order of growth of it? And what about $\sinh\sqrt{z}$?

Comment: for any *even* entire $f$, $f(\sqrt z)$ is entire of order half the order of $f$ (this is non-trivial only if order finite of course); similalry for any *odd* entire $g,  g(\sqrt z)/\sqrt z$ is entire of half the order of $g$; easy proof by using Taylor series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=e^{g(z)}$ where $g(z)^2=z.$ Then $f(0)=1,$ so for $z\ne 0$ we have $$\frac {f(z)-f(0)}{z-0}=\frac {e^{g(z)}-1}{g(z)^2}=$$ $$=\frac {g(z)/1!+g(z)^2/2!+g(z)^3/3+...}{g(z)^2}=A+B$$ where $A=\frac {1}{g(z)}$

and $B=1/2!+g(z)/3!+...$

Now $g(z)\to 0$ as $z\to 0.$ So $B\to 1/2$ as $z\to 0.$ But $A$ does not converge as $z\to 0.$ So $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: Its great. Thanks.